# Go-gin intercepting a request body

Tags: go, go-gin

I am using go-gin as server and trying to decode the request body. When I send request which has both the strings

```
{
    "name": "abc"
}
```

The following code decodes it correctly:

```
var decodedBody map[string]string
err = json.NewDecoder(c.Request.Body).Decode(&decodedBody)
```

But if I send

```
{
    "id": 1
}
```

The following code gives me a blank map

```
var decodedBody map[string]int
err = json.NewDecoder(c.Request.Body).Decode(&decodedBody)
```

Not sure what am I missing here. Any pointers?

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: No error `fmt.Println(decodedBody)` gives me `map[]` instead of `map[id:1]`. The first decoded body is giving me `map[name:abc]` correctly

Comment: Coudn't reproduce https://play.golang.org/p/YzdXR90x0O. Please provide a MVCE.

Answer (score 0):

because you set the decodeBody's data type with string,if your value is not the string value, it will not decode the correct value,{"id":1},it's value's type is int,not the string.